# Golang: How is memory allocated when using `const`/`var` vs in a function?

Tags: go, variables, memory, constants

I'm looking for clarity on how memory is allocated/managed in Go. See example:

```golang
package main

// memory allocated on program startup?
var str1 = "Hello world!"

func createString() string {
  // memory allocated when function is called?
  var str2 = "Another string"
  return str2
}
```

In this example code, how does Go manage the memory of `str1` and `str2`? Does the value of `str1` hang out in memory during the entire runtime of the program?

Can I save on overall program memory usage if I declare string variables inside of function scopes rather than declaring them as global variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string literals "Hello world!" and "Another string" will be in memory no matter how you declare the variables. The `str1` will be initialized to point to "Hello world" literal before main starts, and `str2` will be initialized to point to "Another string" when `createString` runs. Both `str1` and `str2` only contain a pointer and length, so they do not consume much memory.

In short, you cannot save memory based on where you initalize a string using a literal. The literal is what occupies most of the memory, not the string variable.